# Linking static Table View Cell to detailed UINavigationController

Tags: ios, xcode

i've UITableViewController which have static cell. I would like to show another detailed view once user tab on one of the static Table View Cell.

notice, i'm using interface builder with storyboard.

how to to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the storyboard, click on the main TableViewController, then go to the "Editor" menu (very top) and select Embed In > Navigation Controller.

Then Drag a new View Controller to the storyboard. (Yellow Ball with the dashed line square shape)

Then hold down the Control Key and drag from your tablecell to the new view to create a segue. When you release the mouse button, choose "Push."

Note: To set a custom "back button" text, you do so by selecting the "Navigation Item in the Tableview controller, not the detail view.

Hope that helps.